SfGrid Custom Dynamic Styling
I am trying to add colours to a row or the cell based on the selection. I can't seem to find any solution online. Below is the approach I have applied
<SfGrid @ref="SfInventoryGrid" AllowTextWrap="false" AllowExcelExport="true" AllowPdfExport="true"
            AllowSorting="true" DataSource="inventoryData" Toolbar="@toolbar" class="rounded-lg custom-grid" RowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
            <GridEditSettings Mode="EditMode.Normal" AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <span>@(GetDialogHeaderText(context as InventoryModel))</span>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <SfButton OnClick="@Save" IsPrimary="true">@DialogButtonCaption</SfButton>
                    <SfButton OnClick="@Cancel">Cancel</SfButton>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </GridEditSettings>
            <GridEvents OnToolbarClick="OnToolbarClick" OnActionBegin="ActionBeginHandler"
                        OnActionComplete="ActionCompleteHandler" TValue="InventoryModel"></GridEvents>
            <GridToolbar>
                <GridToolBarItems>
                 *****
                </GridToolBarItems>
            </GridToolbar>
            <GridColumns>
                <GridColumn AllowAdding="false" IsPrimaryKey="true" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.Id)" Width="50px">
                </GridColumn>
                <GridColumn Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.Images)" HeaderText="Images" Width="230px">
                    <Template>
                        @{
                            var inventoryModel = context as InventoryModel;
                            var imageUrls = inventoryModel?.Images?.Split(',') ?? new string[0];
                        }
                        <div class="flex space-x-4">
                            @foreach (var imageUrl in imageUrls)
                            {
                                <div class="image">
                                    <img style="width:50px; height:50px;" src="@imageUrl" />
                                </div>
                            }
                            <button @onclick="() => OpenCarousel(imageUrls)" class=""><i class="fa-solid fa-expand text-blue-500 text-md hover:scale-110 ease-in transition-all duration-300"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </Template>
                    <EditTemplate>
                        <div class="flex flex-col py-4 space-y-4">
                            @{
                                var inventoryModel = context as InventoryModel;
                                var imageUrls = inventoryModel?.Images?.Split(',') ?? new string[0];
                            }
                            <div class="flex justify-center items-center space-x-4">
                                @foreach (var imageUrl in imageUrls)
                                {
                                    <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-2">
                                        <img style="width:50px; height:50px;" src="@imageUrl" />
                                        <button type="button" @onclick="@(async () => await RemoveImage(imageUrl))">
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark text-blue-500 text-lg hover:scale-105 ease-in transition-all duration-300"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                            @if (imageUrls.Length >= 3)
                            {
                                <p class="text-xs flex flex-wrap text-red-500">You can only upload up to 3 images. <br> Please delete existing images before <br> adding new ones.</p>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <SfUploader ID="uploadFiles" AllowedExtensions=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" Multiple="true" AutoUpload="true" @ref="Uploader" ValueChange="OnChange">
                                </SfUploader>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </EditTemplate>
                </GridColumn>
                <GridColumn HeaderText="Manufacturer & Description" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.Name)" Width="220px"></GridColumn>
                <GridColumn HeaderText="Location" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.Location)" Width="120px"></GridColumn>

                <GridColumn HeaderText="Quantity" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.Qty)" Width="100px"></GridColumn>

                <GridColumn HeaderText="PN, SN, MODEL, ITEM #" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.Pin)" Width="220px"></GridColumn>
                <GridColumn HeaderText="MRITS" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.MRITS)" Width="120px"></GridColumn>

                <GridColumn HeaderText="TAG" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.TagFirstPart)" Width="150px">
                    <EditTemplate Context="context">
                        @if (context is InventoryModel inventory)
                        {
                            <div class="flex flex-col space-y-4 flex-wrap">
                                <SfTextBox TValue="string" @bind-Value="inventory.TagFirstPart"></SfTextBox>
                                <SfDropDownList TValue="string" TItem="string" Placeholder="Tag colour" DataSource="@colour" @bind-Value="inventory.SelectedColour">
                                    <DropDownListFieldSettings Value="colour" Text="Text"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
                                </SfDropDownList>
                                <SfDropDownList TValue="string" TItem="string" Placeholder="Tag scope" DataSource="@scope" @bind-Value="inventory.SelectedScope">
                                    <DropDownListFieldSettings Value="scope" Text="Text"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
                                </SfDropDownList>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </EditTemplate>
                </GridColumn>

                <GridColumn HeaderText="BARCODE" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.BarCode)" Width="120px"></GridColumn>
                <GridColumn HeaderText="STATUS / NOTES" Field="@nameof(InventoryModel.Status)" Width="120px"></GridColumn>

            </GridColumns>
        </SfGrid>

@code{

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        VisibleProp = true;
        inventoryData = (await inventoryServices.GetInventoryAsync()).ToList();
        foreach (var item in inventoryData)
        {
            item.ParseTag(); // Parse the Tag to set SelectedColour and SelectedScope
        }
        VisibleProp = false;
        await LoadPermissions();
    }

    private void OnRowDataBound(RowDataBoundEventArgs<InventoryModel> args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnRowDataBound called");
        var inventoryModel = args.Data;
        if (inventoryModel != null)
        {
            var selectedColour = inventoryModel.SelectedColour;
            var selectedScope = inventoryModel.SelectedScope.ToLower();
            var className = selectedColour.ToLower();
            
            // Find the row index based on the position of args.Data in inventoryData
            var rowIndex = inventoryData.IndexOf(inventoryModel);

            Console.WriteLine($"Row index: {rowIndex}, Selected Scope: {selectedScope}, Class Name: {className}");

            if (rowIndex != -1)
            {
                if (selectedScope == "row")
                {
                    // Call JavaScript function to apply row style
                    Console.WriteLine("Invoking applyRowStyle");
                    js.InvokeVoidAsync("applyRowStyle", rowIndex, className);
                }
                else if (selectedScope == "cell")
                {
                    var colIndex = 7; // Assuming the column index for TAG is always 7
                    // Call JavaScript function to apply cell style
                    Console.WriteLine("Invoking applyCellStyle");
                    js.InvokeVoidAsync("applyCellStyle", rowIndex, colIndex, className);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


The function OnRowDataBound is not being accessed. What am I doing wrong? I have targeted the data-rowindex and the data-colindex for custom styling. I assume I am following the right approach but somehow I need to make the function work so I can determine whether the right row and col is being accessed.
